# Crashlytics not logging errors in framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics to log errors in my iOS app. This works fine as long as the error occurs in my main app project, but if it happens in one of my frameworks the error isn't logged. Or at least it doesn't appear in the Crashlytics dashboard.

If an error occurs in my framework I log it the same way as I log it in my main project:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
```

Do I have to configure Crashlytics in my framework as well, or will it get access to the same Crashlytics instance I use in my main project? I have only added the run script phase to my main project and start Fabric/Crashlytics by calling `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` in my AppDelegate. Is that enough, or do I have to add the same configuration/logic to my framework as well?

It seems the Crashlytics instance in my framework has the same apiKey and I don't get any errors or crashes when logging the errors in the framework.

Comment: I think you should also write it in framework and make a test crash at the first screen of framework then recompile the framework. I don't know why the first screen thing happens but it resolved the solution for many including me and I also submitted the issue on GitHub, Crashlytics team also noted the issue and are working on it.

Comment: @MoazKhan Do you have a link to the issue on GitHub? What do you mean with "the first screen of framework"?

Comment: I will try to find it again. I think I posted on firebase example project. Sorry first screen of framework doesn't sound right. I mean make some kind of crash in the class that runs first for example when I was facing this issue I was adding the crash after going through many view controllers when I added the crash on first view controller suddenly it started working.